# Upload files in GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I installed Git Bash 1.9.5. I have a repo created at www.github.com. I want to upload a file named test.txt from my local computer to the remote github. I looked at several old questions, but could not find a way to do this. Please help.

I tried `git add test.txt` and then `git push` but not really working. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you fully read the GitHub tutorials? If you did, please provide more information including any errors you get. Also: You need to commit before you push.

Comment: "Not really working" is not really working to convey the output from your commands.

Comment: In my computer, GitBash repo is in "C:/Users/Sambit/localrepo" where I have created a text file called "test.txt" . Now coming to the GitBash console, I write `cd ~/localrepo` to specify my local repository. Then I write `git remote add origin "https://github.com/remoteusername/remoterepo"`, then I write `git add.` followed by `git commit -m "add test.txt"` which says `Changes not staged for commit....no changes added to commit"` then `git push` says `updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally..."` but I did a cloning already

Comment: @user3096833 are you sure you did a `git clone https://github.com/remoteusername/remoterepo C:/Users/Sambit/localrepo` ? Because if you did a `git clone`, you don't need to add a remote. Follow the second approach I mention below and it will work.

Comment: Still throwing error. The cloning statement gives the error `destination path already exists and is not an empty directory` Then the add statement shows lots of warnings and finally gives the error : `unable to index file...` and then `fatal : adding files failed`

Answer (score 0):

In your local repo, you can add the remote url of your remote GitHub repo

```
git remote add origin https://<yourAccount>@github.com/<yourAccount>/<yourRepo)
git commit -m "Add test.txt"
git push -u origin master
```

The other approach would be to clone your repo first, and add your file in it (then `git add .; git commit -m "add test.txt"; git push`)

Answer (score 0):

`git add` adds a file to the index, but it doesn't create a commit.

To create a new commit from the index use `git commit`.

When you have a commit push it with `git push`.

Review what you're doing with `gitk` (for instance).

For more info, see any tutorial on git. For instance: http://www.gitguys.com/topics/whats-the-deal-with-the-git-index/